# weblogic 12.4.X Servlet failed with an Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't reset

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, weblogic, java-ee-6

I am facing peculiar issue on weblogic the execption says:

```
weblogic 12.4.X Servlet failed with an Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't reset
```

StackTrace is as below:

```
<[ServletContext@501586899[app:XXX module:XXX  path:null spec-version:3.1]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't reset
at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.ThresholdOutputStream.reset(ThresholdOutputStream.java:140)
at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingServletOutputStream.reset(CompressingServletOutputStream.java:109)
at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingHttpServletResponse.resetBuffer(CompressingHttpServletResponse.java:287)
at com.dynatrace.agent.introspection.uem.impl.BaseUemResponseHook.resetBuffer(BaseUemResponseHook.java:120)
at com.dynatrace.agent.introspection.uem.impl.AgentInjectingUemResponseHook.resetBuffer(AgentInjectingUemResponseHook.java:305)
at com.dynatrace.agent.introspection.uem.impl.AgentInjectingResponseWrapper.resetBuffer(AgentInjectingResponseWrapper.java:80)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:131)
at com.XXXXX.YYYServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:228)
```

Below is the code:

The same is working in another weblogic managed server, having same version of java.

Simple redirect to a new JSP page.

JSP page is directly accessible, only from the servlet its give this exception in on of the managed servers,
but works on the managed server.

```
if (stringX != null && "Y".equals(stringX )) {
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/MyJSP1.jsp");
} else {
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/MyJSP2.jsp");
}
rd.forward(request, response);//LINE 228
```

Comment: this AgentInjectingResponseWrapper is here when Dynatrace OneAgent software is installed, can it affect?

Comment: I am also facing same issue is this issue solved?